# How to run multiple goroutines and collect results in the same order it runs

Tags: go

I have the following code which has a double-go routine structure:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

func main(){
    outchan := make(chan string)
    for i:=0;i<10;i++{
        go testfun(i, outchan)
    }
    for i:=0;i<10;i++{
        a := <-outchan
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}

func testfun(i int, outchan chan<- string){
    outchan2 := make(chan int)
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond*time.Duration(int64(rand.Intn(10))))
    for j:=0;j<10;j++ {
        go testfun2(j, outchan2)
    }
    tempStr := strconv.FormatInt(int64(i),10)+" - "
    for j:=0;j<10;j++ {
        tempStr = tempStr + strconv.FormatInt(int64(<-outchan2),10)
    }
    outchan <- tempStr
}

func testfun2(j int, outchan2 chan<- int){
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond*time.Duration(int64(rand.Intn(10))))
    outchan2 <- j
}
```

The output I was expecting is

```
0 - 0123456789
1 - 0123456789
2 - 0123456789
3 - 0123456789
4 - 0123456789
5 - 0123456789
6 - 0123456789
7 - 0123456789
8 - 0123456789
9 - 0123456789
```

But instead I got this:

```
7 - 7980345261
6 - 4035897621
3 - 9047526831
9 - 4032861975
8 - 9570831624
5 - 3798021546
1 - 0985362471
0 - 1849276035
2 - 9572806143
4 - 5768032419
```

Could anyone show me how to achieve the output I was expecting? I'm a newbie and please forgive me if the solution is obvious. I've been looking for it for days.

Comment: This is more of a generic problem than a go problem, it's a generic issue of maintaining order in a multithreaded app. Some of the queueing strategies discussed here should help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227042/maintaining-order-in-a-multi-threaded-pipeline#answer-3228846

Comment: The results you get are in exactly the same order they were calculated and sent to the channel. what is the actual problem you are trying to solve? Maybe the easiest solution would be to not use goroutines?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To give you a better idea. The issue is that you're reading a single channel where the values that are pushed onto the channel are in an arbitrary order due to your `time.Sleep` calls. If you want to issue the `time.Sleep` calls concurrently to simulate concurrent long-running processes, what you'll want to do is make each goroutine write to a channel with the results.

This way you can iterate across an in-order list of the results channels blocking until the next channel can be read from (the same idea as the output queue in this answer [Maintaining Order in a Multi-Threaded Pipeline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3227042/maintaining-order-in-a-multi-threaded-pipeline#answer-3228846)) Here's your reworked code with some name changes to make things easier to track:

```
package main

import(
    "fmt"
    "math/rand"
    "time"
    "strconv"
)

func main(){
    var jobs []chan string
    for i := 0; i<10; i++{
        job := make(chan string)
        jobs = append(jobs, job)
        go testfun(i, job)
    }
    for _, result := range jobs {
      fmt.Println(<-result)
    }
}

func testfun(i int, job chan<- string){
    var innerJobs []chan int
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond*time.Duration(int64(rand.Intn(10))))
    for j := 0; j<10; j++ {
        innerJob := make(chan int)
        innerJobs = append(innerJobs, innerJob)
        go testfun2(j, innerJob)
    }
    tempStr := strconv.FormatInt(int64(i),10)+" - "
    for _, result := range innerJobs {
      tempStr = tempStr + strconv.FormatInt(int64(<-result),10)
    }
    job <- tempStr
}

func testfun2(j int, innerJob chan<- int){
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond*time.Duration(int64(rand.Intn(10))))
    innerJob <- j
}
```

Answer (score 3):

A different / more efficient approach is using a slice (or an array) and using a `sync.WaitGroup`:

```
func main() {
    var wg sync.WaitGroup
    out := make([]string, 10)
    for i := 0; i < len(out); i++ {
        wg.Add(1)
        go testfun(i, &out[i], &wg)
    }
    wg.Wait()
    for i := 0; i < len(out); i++ {
        a := out[i]
        fmt.Println(a)
    }
}

func testfun(i int, outVal *string, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    //........
    *outVal = tempStr
    wg.Done()
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/4C1hl64Xzw)

*edit*: updated the example for testfun2 as well, forgot about that.